# String index out of range at line 27

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a basic Ceaser cipher with non-complicated code and when I type something like Go Buy Bread and set the shift to 8 or higher I get an error called string index out of range and I don't want to use mod (%) can anyone give me a solution?

```
Alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 -!?.'


FinalMessage = ''


print("Cipher/Decipher Code")
print("-")
print("This code can encode messages and decode messages.")


while True:
    print()
    Option = int(input('Type the number 1 to encode your message, number 2 to decode, number 3 to exit: '))  
    print()                                                                                                  
    if Option == 1:  
        Message = list(input("Type the message you want to encode: "))  
        print()                                                         
        print("To encode the message type a number between 1 and 26.")  
        print("The number means how many letters the message will shift.")
        Key = int(input("Number: "))  
        for Cipher in Message:  
            if Cipher in Alphabet:  
                Position = Alphabet.find(Cipher) 
                NewPosition = (Position + Key)
                NewCipher = Alphabet[NewPosition]
                FinalMessage += NewCipher  
            else:  
                FinalMessage += Cipher 
        print()
        print("Encrypted Message: " + FinalMessage) 
        print()
        print("------")
        print()
    elif Option == 2:
        print()
        Message = list(input("Type the message you want to decode: "))
        print()
        print("To decode a message type a number between 1 and 26.") 
        print("The number means how many letters the message will shift")  
        Key = int(input("Number: "))  
        Key = (Key * -1) 
        for Cipher in Message:  
            if Cipher in Alphabet: 
                Position = Alphabet.find(Cipher) 
                NewPosition = (Position + Key)
                NewCipher = Alphabet[NewPosition]
                FinalMessage += NewCipher
            else:  
                FinalMessage += Cipher 
        print()
        print("Decrypted Message: " + FinalMessage) 
        print()
        print("------")
        print()
    FinalMessage = ""
```

Comment: If you don't want to use `%`, you can use `-` instead, it's just a little more difficult.

Comment: `NewCipher = Alphabet[NewPosition]` Its very dangerous to increment the index of a list, bc as you are nearing the last few elements, the new position becomes greater than list length. Pretty self explanatory error, what you want is a check to see if index/position is greater than list lenght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure *why* you wouldn't want to use `%`, it seems ideal for this. Otherwise, you'll have to manually check if the adjusted index is beyond the range of the alphabet and add/subtract the size of the alphabet to wrap around properly.

The two methods would be:

```py
# Method 1 (preferred).

NewPosition = (Position + Key) % len(Alphabet)

# Method 2 (ugly and unnecessary).

NewPosition = Position + Key
if NewPosition >= len(Alphabet):
    NewPosition -= len(Alphabet)
```

However, `Go Buy Bread` with a shift of (positive) eight wouldn't give a wrapping problem with the alpha characters as all the results are still within the string. It may if you *subtract* eight but I'm assuming here you want to encode the plaintext message rather than decode it.

So your best bet would be to start debugging by printing out `Position` and `NewPosition` (and `len(Alphabet)` as well) each time through the loop. That should hopefully tell you what's happening.